# Custom TFS 2013 activity to merge one branch to another

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS 2013 and need to write a custom TFS activity that auto-merges from one branch to another.

So for example merge code from...

$/Parent

to...

$/Other/Parent

If one were to assume a happy path where there are no merge conflicts, can someone show a simple code segment that merges from $/Parent to $/Other/Parent please?

I have found an example for earlier versions of TFS, but the API has changed for 2013, and I am not seeing how to translate it.  Here is a link for how to do it in XAML for versions prior to 2010.

[Automate Merge With TFS Build](http://joemwalton.com/blog/?p=927)

I am seeking a C# code example that does the same thing for 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create custom activities. They are difficult to debug and are only supported for legacy in 2015. Create a PowerShell script that completed the task (you can still call c# in there). The 2013 template has slots for running PowerShell and your scripts will work in the new build system in 2015.

Comment: so calling 'tf merge' from PowerShell is the best way to go? and how do you determine if it worked or not?